# Pass $_GET to Script (AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to pass **$recptid = $_GET['id'];** To the following

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#name').keypress(function(event) {
            var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (key == 13) {
                var info = $('#name').val();
                                    $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",

                    //need to pass my get variable  
                    url: "message_action.php",
                    data: {name: info},
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#result').append(status);
                        $('#name').val('');
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which then executes message_action.php query's as at the moment my error is Undefined variable: recptid . As my query cannot access it due to been in separate file for AJAX

How can I pass $recptid to message_action.php  please?

Comment: Let me get this clear, you wanna pass your get data in the URL to another php file via ajax?

Comment: If you want `id` to appear in $_GET, why are you not listing it in `data:{name:info}`? you only get what you TELL jquery/ajax to send, and you're not telling it anything about your id value.

Comment: @marcb Thanks , I know for future to always include in data:{name:info}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `data: {name: info},` just put the thing too.. `data: {name: info, recptid: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>'},` then in *message_action.php* just use $_POST['recptid']; (use post since your AJAX Call uses POST method)

Answer (score 0):

```
var receiptFromPHP = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']) ?>";
//now you can use receipt in javascript.
```

Now in AJAX use:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",

   //need to pass my get variable  
   url: "message_action.php",
   data: {
     name: info,
     receipt: receiptFromPHP
   },
   success: function(status) {
     $('#result').append(status);
     $('#name').val('');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you try to send 'id' with $.ajax to 'message_action.php'. If so, you use post method, not get so you have to use the same method to receive it in 'message_action.php'

```
$recptid = $_POST['id']
```

and you have to include id in your post data

```
data:{name: info, id: id}
```